# Compare objects contained in a map

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I have to do an exercise and I need a little bit of help.

I have two objects called teacher1 and teacher2 with the attributes name and age:

```
Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher();
Teacher teacher2 = new Teacher();
teacher1.newTeacher("David", 26);
teacher2.newTeacher("Douglas", 26);
```

newTeacher is a constructor of the class Teacher, contained in another class called Teacher.class, that contains

```
public class Teacher {

String name;
int age;

    public void newTeacher(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

I have to put each one in a different Map with a String as key:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object();
HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object();
map1.put("123A",teacher1);
map2.put("456B",teacher2);
```

Then I have to access them from each Map and compare their attributes.

Can you help me with this last step?

Comment: Why have you got two maps, and why have you declared them with a value type of `Object` instead of `Teacher`? What does your `newTeacher` method do (and why aren't you just passing those values into the constructor)? At the moment this question is too vague for us to help you.

Comment: This code looks wrong. Could you add an explanation of what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I added more information if it can help. I have to access each object from the Maps and compare the name and age of each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fairly straight forward if you just want to iterate them to compare. Check this :-

```
for(Map.Entry obj1 : map1.entrySet()){
    for(Map.Entry obj2 : map2.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("OBJ 1 : "+obj1.getKey()+", "+((Teacher)obj1.getValue()).getName()+", "+((Teacher)obj1.getValue()).getAge());
        System.out.println("OBJ 2 : "+obj2.getKey()+", "+((Teacher)obj2.getValue()).getName()+", "+((Teacher)obj2.getValue()).getAge());
    }
}
```

PS:- Just to put working code i have directly typecasted it to Teacher but you should use instanceof & null check before doing that as you have declared hashmap to store Object as value rather than specifically Teacher.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of what you are trying to do is correct, one way to go about it is to implement [`equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) in your `Teacher` class, then get the instances (say `teacherA` and `teacherB`) from your map by calling `Map.get(String)` with the key as the argument and then do `if (teacherA.equals(teacherB))...`.

In your implementation of `equals(Object)` you can define your rules to determine whether 2 teachers are equal (in your case it would probably be that they have same `name` and `age`).

However your code has errors, f.ex. your `newTeacher(String, int)` is not the constructor of the class `Teacher`, it's just a method that sets values into the fields `name` and `age` of the instance on which you call that method. You should give another read to the doc, f.ex. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html .

Also, as good practice, you should declare your `map1` and `map2` using the interface (`Map`) instead of `HashMap` or any other concrete implementations of `Map` interface. And as pointed out in comments that should be `Map<String, Teacher>`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use proper constructor and use strict typing in your hashmaps.
Your snippet is wrong in many ways.

```
public final class Teacher {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Teacher(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

-

```
    Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("David", 26);
    Teacher teacher2 = new Teacher("Douglas", 26);

    HashMap<String, Teacher> map1 = new HashMap<String, Teacher>();
    HashMap<String, Teacher> map2 = new HashMap<String, Teacher>();
    map1.put("123A",teacher1);
    map2.put("456B",teacher2);

    for (Teacher t1 : map1.values()) {
        for (Teacher t2 : map2.values()) {
            if (t1.getName().equals(t2.getName())) {
                System.out.println("name compares");
            } else {
                System.out.println("name not compares");
            }

            if (t1.getAge() == t2.getAge()) {
                System.out.println("age compares");
            } else {
                System.out.println("age not compares");
            }
        }
    }
```